# Facebook like button does not appear

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

It seems that I have a problem making Facebook-like button appear on my site. I think I did exactly what the instructions say. I have read dozens of posts (here and other forums) and still nothing changes. I have tried all versions (html5, xfbml, iframe). Strangely, like-box appears only on Opera.

My site is behind an SSL layer.

Comment: Its visible in Chrome but not in Firefox & IE 9 at my end

Comment: downvote? why? What was wrong?

Comment: It's visible in Chrome, but not in IE 8. Please see the [facebook debugger output](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Ftipleaders.com%2Ftl%2F0%2F) as thomasbabuj suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I debug the your URL in facebook debugger, it throws some [Warnings](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://tipleaders.com) !  Please update as per the debugger suggestions.

Currently your page has a Error "FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem" - you can check that via firebug console.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=119488114856726";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div style='float: right; margin-top: 25px; display: inline-block' class="fb-like" data-href="https://tipleaders.com/" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="40" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
```

Kindly replace this code in body tag.  Hope this will solves your problem.

Please checkout this [page - Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Answer (score 2):

works find in firefox at least, i can see the like button. but it is in the left column. just make sure the site where the like button appears is visible without any login, because facebook needs to have access to it.

btw, i am getting the following errors in the browser console:

"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://tipleaders.com/tl/h//?ajax="

"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://tipleaders.com/count_classified//?ajax=&status=false&count=0"

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this: "just make sure the site where the like button appears is visible without any login"? Concerning the errors I know. I will correct them soon.

Comment: it means: facebook has to be able to REACH the page that is linked to in the like button. the facebook crawler, to be specific. google also cannot just put a page in his database when it´s secured with a user login.